# Selenium, php, phpUnit, 404 error calls testComplete() rather than continue, how do I stop this?

Tags: php, testing, selenium, phpunit

Selenium, php, phpUnit, 404 error calls testComplete() rather than continue, how do I stop this?

I am using selenium server and phpUnit to run php based tests. My tests are simple, test the page is there, if it loads, has no errors on page and then move on. I have a missing page and rather than say, yep its not there and more on I get:

Time: 16 seconds, Memory: 14.75Mb

There was 1 error:

1) OlympicsSiteMapEnglishPages::testMyTestCase
PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Response from Selenium RC server for testComplete().
XHR ERROR: URL = http://my.url/somepage Response_Code = 404 Error_Message = Not Found.

/some/path/some_file.php:375

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.

I really need to figure out how to stop it doing this! I have tried catching the exception like so:

try {
        $this->open("/rel/url.php", 1);
    } catch (PHPUnit_Framework_AssertionFailedError $e) {
        return array_push($this->verificationErrors, $e->toString());
    }

Any clues guys, I really need help!

Many thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 1):

- `PHPUnit_Framework_Exception` inherits from `Exception`
- `PHPUnit_Framework_AssertionFailedError` inherits from `Exception`

If you want to catch them both, you'll either have to catch the 'sort of expected' `PHPUnit_Framework_Exception` earlier on (and possibly rethrow it as an `PHPUnit_Framework_AssertionFailedError`), or resort to the generic `try{} catch(Exception $e){}`

Answer (score 0):

Right after a bit of digging nothing works, so my hackie hack way which is very slow, it to try and open each url first using:

if(@fopen(rtrim($this->url, "/") . "/blah/blah/blah","r"))
{

//do some test which should now not exit the browser as we know the page exists.

}

Please could some one find a much better way of doing things!